# Obtener el listado de options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de obtener con jQuery el listado de valores de "options" que tiene un selector. Me gustaría hacerlo en una sola línea.

Tengo aquí un ejemplo:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var array_opciones = [];
  var opciones = $('#miselect').children();
  for (i=0;i<opciones.length;i++) {
    array_opciones.push(opciones[i].value);
  }
  console.log(array_opciones);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="miselect" size="4">
    <option value='Manzana'>Apple</option>
    <option value='Naranja'>Orange</option>
    <option value='Piña'>Pineapple</option>
    <option value='Platano'>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p>Abre la consola de javascript y haz click para ver el resultado</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK AQUÍ</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo mas limpio que he podido obtener, pero imagino que debe haber alguna forma mejor de obtener los values con jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes hecho no está mal. Pero podrías reducir el número de líneas usando la función `each()` de **JQuery**. Esta lo que hace es iterar por cada elemento del conjunto que le pases al selector.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var array_opciones = [];
  var opciones = $('#miselect').children();
  for (i=0;i<opciones.length;i++) {
    array_opciones.push(opciones[i].value);
  }
  console.log(array_opciones);
}

function myFunction2 () {
  $("#miselect option").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="miselect" size="4">
    <option value='Manzana'>Apple</option>
    <option value='Naranja'>Orange</option>
    <option value='Piña'>Pineapple</option>
    <option value='Platano'>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>

<p>Abre la consola de javascript y haz click para ver el resultado</p>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">CLICK AQUÍ</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En una sola línea se puede usar `map()` o `$.map()`:

```js
const values = [...$("#miselect option")].map(e => e.value);

console.log(values);

const values2 = $.map($("#miselect option"), (e) => e.value);

console.log(values2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="miselect" size="4">
  <option value='Manzana'>Apple</option>
  <option value='Naranja'>Orange</option>
  <option value='Piña'>Pineapple</option>
  <option value='Platano'>Banana</option>
</select>
```